# Why does this program double print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't isolate the problem. The program is supposed to take two integers and convert them to scientific notation, then multiply them. However it prints the scientific notion twice. However it prints the information twice.

```
def convert(s):
    print("You typed " + s)
    n=0
    for c in s:
        n=n+1
        if n==1:
            print("In scientific notation:"+str(c)+'.', end='')
        if n!=1:
            print(str(c),end='')
    print('X 10^'+str(len(s)-1))
    return c

def convert_product(u):
    n=0
    for c in u:
        n=n+1
        if n==1:
            print("Product in scientific notation "+c+'.', end='')
        if n!=1:
            print(c, end='')


def main():
    s=input("Please input your first number\n")
    t=input("Please input your second number\n")
    u=str(int(convert(s))*int(convert(t)))
    convert(s)
    convert(t)
    convert_product(u)
    print('X 10^' + str(len(s)+len(t)-2))
main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling convert in this line :

```
u=str(int(convert(s))*int(convert(t)))
```

And you are calling convert again on the numbers :

```
convert(s)
convert(t)
```

And the convert function is printing. Thus you have dual prints.

Comment: +1. This is the case when a function has so called *side effect*. You should avoid that. Instead of printing, return the string or one or more values. Then the caller can decide what to do with the result.